# Facebook Share in my website keeps redirecting to website home?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website that I want to share to facebook

https://pvp5.com/item/12057/Sakura-Transient-House

But when facebook fetch the url it always fetch the home url

https://pvp5.com/home

I have a screenshot to prove it. I also did a basic troubleshooting turning off my caching mechanism and website page rules. Why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

Because you explicitly said so, by specifying the Canonical URL as `https://pvp5.com/home` for all pages.

The canonical URL should be set to the individual URL of that article/piece of content you want to share.

Comment: Thanks it was solve after removing the canonical url.